# GCP CLB: how to get X-Forwarded-For IP in Nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

According GCP doc, https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#target-proxies, `X-Forwarded-For` contains **multiple** IPs, eg `1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8`, where `1.2.3.4` is the real client IP, `5.6.7.8` is the CLB IP.

How can I get `1.2.3.4` in `nginx.conf`? I want to use it with geoip.

Comment: You can use the [real IP module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) to break down `X-Forwarded-For` and set the `$remote_addr` variable with the proper value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [real IP module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) to break down `X-Forwarded-For` and set the `$remote_addr` variable with the proper value.

For example:

```
set_real_ip_from  5.6.7.8;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

The value of `$remote_addr` is changed from `5.6.7.8` to `1.2.3.4`.

In many distributions of Nginx, this module is already present. Use `nginx -V` to confirm which modules are present.